# Forbid rvalue binding via constructor to member const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, pass-by-const-reference

I am working on a matrix view class, of which constructor takes a matrix as a parameter and binds it to a `const` reference member. I would very much like to avoid binding rvalues, since they don't bind via a constructor parameter, and we end up with a dangling reference. I came up with the following (simplified code):

```
struct Foo{};

class X
{
    const Foo& _foo;
public:    
    X(const Foo&&) = delete;       // prevents rvalue binding
    X(const Foo& foo): _foo(foo){} // lvalue is OK
};

Foo get_Foo()
{
    return {};
}

const Foo get_const_Foo()
{
    return {};
}

Foo& get_lvalue_Foo()
{
    static Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main() 
{
//  X x1{get_Foo()};        // does not compile, use of deleted function
//  X x2{get_const_Foo()};  // does not compile, use of deleted function
    X x3{get_lvalue_Foo()}; // this should be OK
}
```

Basically I delete the constructor that takes `const Foo&&` as a parameter. Note that I need the `const` since otherwise someone may return `const Foo` from a function, and in that case it will bind to the `const Foo&` constructor.

**Question:**

Is this the correct paradigm of disable rvalue binding? Am I missing something?

Comment: There isn't really much to say here regarding programming; I think it should be on codereview.se.

Comment: `const Foo&&` is pointless

Comment: @DieterLücking That's what I thought first also, but it's not. Try removing the `const` and the second commented line will compile.

Comment: Side note: `const Foo get_const_Foo()` is already fishy

Comment: @DieterLücking Totally agree, but I've seen it in production code (Eigen library uses it, and need to take care of it). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33202145/3093378, which was the source for this question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, this is exactly what [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper) does. Its deleted constructor takes `T&&` because the other constructor takes `T&`. You could do the same and have `View<T>` be a mutable view into the matrix, while `View<T const>` is a const view.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the link! The `reference_wrapper` seems the most elegant way of doing it.